# Atomic configuration along optic axis

Tags: optics, waves, crystals

How does the atomic configuration define a specific direction in a crystal called optic axis along which no birefrigence take place? What is so special about that particular axis ? What is the feature of atomic configuration in a dichroic crystal along optic axis?